# IPv4 Public IP and Public DNS (IPv4) serving different content

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a Django-nginx-gunicorn app running on a AWS EC2 instance. I have configured nginx successfully and can get all content on the public IP. But the same is not happening on the external DNS hostname provided by AWS (example: ec2-203-0-113-25.compute-1.amazonaws.com). Mine is still rendering the nginx default page. The public IP x.x.x.x is serving the Django App content.

Here is `server` part of nginx.conf:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name X.X.X.X; # Has the Public IP address here
        access_log /var/log/nginx-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx-error.log;
        root /home/ubuntu/project/ToDo-application/;
        location /static {
                root /home/ubuntu/ToDo-application/frontend;
        }

        location / {
                include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
                default_type application/octet-stream;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

How do i get the default DNS to serve the same content as the Public IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the server_name from your config:

```
    server_name X.X.X.X
```

Change:

```
    listen 80;
```

To:

```
    listen *:80;
```

Check /etc/nginx/sites-available and/or /etc/nginx/sites-enabled, there should be a default config file (default). My guess is that’s holding the default config that your DNS is pointing to and rendering the html under /var/www/html.

Comment out the content in that file... then, restart nginx:

```
    service nginx restart
```

What’s happening here is that one config is telling nginx to bind to port 80 but look for a header of your public IP, the other config (default config) is probably telling it to use DNS as the server name. By doing a bind to *:80, with no server name, your telling nginx to serve your config on all IP addresses regardless of server name header.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Give the following a try:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name X.X.X.X; # Has the Public IP address here
        access_log /var/log/nginx-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx-error.log;
        root /home/ubuntu/project/ToDo-application/;
        location /static {
                root /home/ubuntu/ToDo-application/frontend;
        }

        location / {
                include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
                default_type application/octet-stream;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

According to the official [Nginx documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html), usage of `default_server` can tell Nginx that a particular `server` definition should be the default listener for a given port.

It's also worth noting that you can include multiple domain names, IPs, and Regex patterns on one `server_name` line to indicate that the server should block is intended to handle of the listed options.

Comment: I tried your method and restarted nginx but if failed. so i ran `nginx -t` and got this message `nginx: [emerg] a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:66
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed` line 66 is `listen 80 default_server;`